HELP: I sent funds on ETH BASE to ETH USDC
Hello I accidentally sent funds I had on the BASE ETH network to ETH USDC is it lost forever?
edit: sorry this was me panicking not knowing what to do. i went to coinbase wallet and found my usdc sitting for me there. i was panicking as i initiated everything on the phantom wallet and didnt see usdc eth there so i was panicking.
sorry

Please provide more details like transaction hashes and wallets involved. Usually tokens transfers between different networks require a bridge.
